# How to pad a div without extending the border?

Tags: css, border, padding

I have this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.container {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #999999;
    width:500px;
    padding-left:200px
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">asdf</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And it works fine except for the fact that the bottom border is also applied to the 200px before the indent. I want the bottom border to start at 200px. Can this be done?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use margin instead of padding or use an inner div.. (updated to match requirements disclosed in comments)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {            
            width:500px;
            padding-left:200px
        }
        .inner{
            border-bottom: 1px dotted #999999;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="inner">
            asdf</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is what it should look like: http://jsfiddle.net/dKVTb/1/

Comment: Then add a child div that has the contents and either add padding to the outer, or margin to the inner.

Answer (score 1):

If that's the case, use this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        content here
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.container {    
    padding-left:200px;
}
.content {    
    width:500px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #999999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this, with `margin-left`

http://jsfiddle.net/ppMmy/

> The CSS padding properties define the
>   space between the element border and
>   the element content.

Thus not "padding" the whole `<div>`